# To filter gps co-ordinates that matches with the previous layer

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a two .csv files with sets of gps co-ordinates in it. After plotting the gps co-ordinates from two files as separate layers, I need to filter a particular road which matches from the two layers and remove the remaining co-ordinates from the attribute table and save these co-ordinates back as a .csv file.

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Gokul, am I correctly understand that you want to construct the round over the pattern that has the most matches?